# Where should ViewModel/View's properties be stored?

Tags: wpf, architecture, mvvm

Simple example: 
I have VM with hierarchical item structure and I have designed View containing TreeView. Each tree node corresponds to data item related to the one in the Model. 
GUI must respect user preferences and settings and store different parameters including whether each particular node is expanded or not. As long as every node relates to some data we need to tie View settings with the Model. I beleive it's not OK to define property IsExpanded in the class standing for the Model.

So where should I store the settings so they stayed consistent with the data?

Comment: Why would you need IsExpanded in your ViewModel Pattern if it is not related to the ViewModelItem? The only way I could think of doing this properly is to wrap your ViewModelItem inside a second ViewModelItem. Please explain the need for IsExpanded.

Comment: Imagine list of topics with questions. Topics are level 0 nodes. Questions - level 1.  I want GUI to remember what topics were expanded and collapsed. These topics can be deleted somewhere else so I need to know which node is old and its state was persisted.

Comment: Than it's part of the ViewModelItem, every viewModelItem regardless whether it's Topic or Question. If is thrives on IsExpanded than it should be a member, otherwise just encapsulate the ViewModelItem with a second ViewModelItem Containing the first and a Boolean for the IsExpanded state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation, here's what I did to solve it.

Each ViewModel node had an IsExpanded property, which was bound to the TreeViewItem's IsExpanded property. I didn't want to persist the state of the tree by storing it in the Model in IsExpanded properties (it's to do with visual state right?). So instead, I had the VM tree structure generate a dictionary that stored the expansion state for each node against a string key generated from the node's state in the tree:

`Dictionary<string, bool> treeExpandedStates`

Each node in the tree had an ID, so in my case the key was something like "/1/3/7", but anything unique will do. This Dictionary was then serialized to a file on application close (in actual fact it was a SerializableDictionary). Then on application restart, it was deserialized and used to set the expansion state after the hierarchy had been loaded back up. This meant that the state of the tree was exactly as the user had left it, but nothing was stored in the Model.

Comment: This is like I meant with my approach B :)

Answer (score 3):

> I believe it's not OK to define property IsExpaned in the class standing for the Model.

Why? Will there be occassions when the model is linked to two different tree-views?

If that is the case you can certainly create an "adapter view-model" that wraps your models and adds the property. Just be careful because that can technique can easily lead to a memory leak.

Otherwise, it is perfectly acceptable to put it right in the model, especially if that model is being used specifically to serve that view. As with all things, start with the simplest, most pragmatic approach.

Comment: I think it breaks the paradigm. Including IsExpanding implicitly connects Model and View. I think over another approach. Each data should provide Id. And ViewModel can pair item's Id and its settings.
Neverthe less I do agree with you:  As with all things, start with the simplest, most pragmatic approach

Comment: I should read up on MVVM:) A wrappermodel would be best I guess but why is it called MVVM and not MWVVWM, just kidding.

Comment: By the way, I'm not he main question asker here but could you eleborate a little bit on the memory leak?

Comment: @Silvermind It's a known issue with POCOs not supporting INotifyPropertyChanged. When binding data PropertyDescriptor is listened for ValueChangedEvent to implement dependent properties update in case of TwoWay binding. So object is stored in memory forever. http://www.benbarefield.com/blog/?p=59

Comment: @Silvermind. Let's say the PersonVM has a FullName property. In order to generate a property change notification for this property, the PersonVM needs to listen to events on the PersonModel. If the PersonVM goes out of scope without removing the event listener, it will be leaked by the PersonModel event.

Comment: @Silvermind: Another problem scenario is collections and other complex childern. You can end up having to create two complete object graphs, a model graph and a view-model graph. Keeping them synchronized is really, really hard, especially when you try to ensure event handlers are removed at the right time.

Comment: So what happens when I change the DataContext to another class, would the removed class PropertyChanged event not be unsubscribed? Thank you for your interest, I really appreciate it.

Comment: XAML data binding uses weak events, so no worry there. It's when you explicitly add an event handler that you need to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize the problem as a common dilemma in MVVM. I can look at it from two sides.

### Approach A)

In the separation of View, Model, and ViewModel, what you describe **resides in the Model**. You write for example that it needs to be stored. That does not mean it is the same part of the model as the other model data.

Consider the following separation:

- **FolderModel** - A model of the content or properties of a folder.
- **TreeNodeModel** - A model of a users choices when exploring the tree view.

It might not be that easy to do a separation just like that, but the point is that MVVM is not meant to force you to stuff everything in the same place, and I do not think MVVM prevents you from keeping models for user interactions, the same way as you keep models for data content. [Microsoft writes:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090102)

> The data could come from a database, a Web service, a named pipe, a file on disk, or even carrier pigeons: it simply does not matter.

Why should not data for a data model be able to come from interactions of a user? :)

### Approach B)

**My usual approach to these dilemmas**, though, is that properties like `IsExpanded` does mostly not need to be stored between sessions. That way, a property in the ViewModel, with a default value instead of a stored value, suffices. :)

And if it needs to be stored, it does not need to be stored in the Model. The ViewModel is for logic for presenting model data. If the ViewModel wants to save its logic state, that **does not have to be stored in the Model**.

### Summary

In my point of view, you can store it any of these ways without breaking the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I think MVVM is pushed too far in some situations, because a lot of people asking question about MVVM here look like they can't wrap their head around it. There is a good chance I will be wrong, but I think MVVM can be quite handy for large projects, but people should focus little on reflecting their database values with (almost exact duplicate) ViewModelItems. I think people tend to forget there is a two-way relationship between the UI and the ViewModelItems. Not just the One-way from the ViewModelItems to the UI. But I could be SO wrong.

Comment: It's not forgetting.
I just start design from user experience and adapt VM to the View but still try to make VM less connected (logically) to the View. It gives GUI designer sensible degree of freedom to change some UI (not just look and feel) parts without disturbing programmers. But it costs more coding cause VM needs to be overdetailed just in case to provide functionality for new possible interaction scenarios. Sure in simple UIs it's easier to rewrite the code of VM from scratch rather than being prepared for everything =)

Comment: Unlike some patterns (e.g. Dependency Injection), MVVM doesn't become more useful as the size of the application grows. If the particular flavor of MVVM you are using doesn't make your small application easier, it won't make you large application easier either.

Comment: I think this answer really made things click for me. It can be stored in the model, but not synced to database. Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation.